# Change BenchmarkDotnet exporter path

Tags: benchmarkdotnet

The documentation says that "by default" the exporters will create a report in the `.\BenchmarkDotNet.Artifacts\results` path.

Is there a way to override this path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done via the `ArtifactsPath` property in `IConfig` as explained [here](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet/issues/1819)